# React Native Routing

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

How can go to the next page when I pressed a button without using the NavigatorIOS. is there a way in react native to do that?

I understand how the NavigatorIOS works but my problem is i do not want to have NavigationBar on my Login Page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NavigatorIOS` has a property `navigationBarHidden` that you could set when you are in the login screen, e.g. something like:

```
<NavigatorIOS
  navigationBarHidden={!this.state.isLoggedIn}
  //...
/>
```

Alternatively you could render your login screen outside the navigator hierarchy:

```
render: function() {
  if (!this.state.isLoggedIn) {
    return <LoginScreen />;
  }
  return (
    <NavigatorIOS
      //...
    />
  );
},
```

Both of these examples presume that your button sets a state variable `isLoggedIn` to `true`.